# nanoScroller, check if slider is at the bottom

Tags: jquery

I am using this custom scrollbar generator for a project : http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Is there a way to check if the `slider` is at the bottom of the `pane`? It has a built in function to check if the slider has reached the end when dragging.

```
$(".nano").bind("scrollend", function(e){
    // do something
});
```

However, I want to check without initiating drag event.

Answer (score 1):

Needed the same. Here is what's worked for me.

```
var elem = $('.content')
if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()) {
    console.log('at bottom')
} else {
    console.log('NOT at bottom')
}
```

**Note:** Bind it on the .content class. It's the inner from the .nano class. Then it should work perfectly.